# How to use org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.widgets.SWTBotTree.getNode(String nodeText,int index) method?

Tags: java, swt, swtbot

I am using this method in my framework and it started giving me exception like " org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.exceptions.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed: The index (1) was more than the number of nodes (1) in the tree."

Following is the structure:

```
<RootNode>
    <ChildNode1>
        <GrandChildNode1/>
    </ChildNode1>
    <ChildNode2/>
</RootNode>
```

Below is the code. If I print the node at index 2 in "isTreeNodeWithIndexPresent" method, it gives correct as "ChildNode2". It only thrown exception when goes through the getNode method.

```
public boolean isTreeNodeWithIndexPresent(final String node, final int nodeIndex) {
    boolean status = false;
    if (node.length() > 0) {
        final SWTBotTreeItem[] botTreeItem = tree.getAllItems();
        for (final SWTBotTreeItem swtBotTreeItem : botTreeItem) {
            status = swtBotTreeItem.getNode(node, nodeIndex).isVisible();
        }
    }
    return status;
}.

    public SWTBotTreeItem getNode(final String nodeText, final int index) {
            List<SWTBotTreeItem> nodes = getNodes(nodeText);
            Assert.isTrue(index < nodes.size(),
                    MessageFormat.format("The index ({0}) was more than the number of nodes ({1}) in the tree.", index, nodes.size()));
            return nodes.get(index);
        }
```

Comment: Why you loop through all the nodes? You have nodeIndex which I think is index based on the whole tree but in the loop you ask the treeItem about node with that index?

Comment: Are you asking about the getNode method? that is method written by SWTBOT.

Answer (score 0):

`SWTBotTreeItem#getNode(nodeText, index)` returns the node with the given text that is a *direct* child of the item the method is called on.

The index can be used in case the tree item has multiple nodes with the same name. For example, if you have two children with name "foobar" you can access the second node with `item.getNode("foobar", 1)` (and the first with `item.getNode("foobar", 0)` or `item.getNode("foobar")`).